# How to display a website inside a chrome extension iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sidebar, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

This is my Manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Knowledge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Adds an iframe to all websites",
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-modals; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; child-src 'self';"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://*.w3builders.in/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icon128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*.w3builders.in/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "content.html",
        "content.js",
        "images/icon16.png",
        "images/icon48.png",
        "images/icon128.png",
        "https://w3builders.in/TeachMentorAI/login"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://*.w3builders.in/*"
      ],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my content.js file

```
// content.js
function toggleSidebar() {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("https://w3builders.in/TeachMentorAI/login");
  // iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("content.html");
  iframe.style.position = "fixed";
  iframe.style.right = "-300px";
  iframe.style.top = "0px";
  iframe.style.width = "300px";
  iframe.style.height = "100%";
  // iframe.style.zIndex = "999999";
  iframe.style.zIndex = "9999999999";
  iframe.style.background = "rgba(255, 255, 255)";
  iframe.style.boxShadow = "0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)";
  // iframe.style.backdropFilter = "blur(8.7px)";
  // iframe.style.webkitBackdropFilter = "blur(8.7px)";
  iframe.style.border = "1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)";
  iframe.style.transition = "right 0.3s ease-in-out";

  iframe.onerror = function () {
    console.error("Failed to load iframe.");
  };

  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  // Add a button to toggle the sidebar
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerText = "...";
  button.style.position = "fixed";
  button.style.top = "6px";
  button.style.right = "-28px";
  // button.style.zIndex = "999998";
  button.style.zIndex = "2147483646";
  button.style.background = "red";
  button.style.width = "60px";
  button.style.padding = "10px";
  button.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
  button.style.display = "flex";
  button.style.justifyContent = "center";
  button.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "5px";
  button.style.borderBottomRightRadius = "5px";
  button.style.border = "none";
  button.style.color = "white";
  button.style.fontSize = "25px";
  button.style.transition = "right 0.3s ease-in-out";

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    iframe.style.right = iframe.style.right === "0px" ? "-300px" : "0px";
    button.style.right = button.style.right === "-28px" ? "270px" : "-28px";
  });

  document.body.appendChild(button);
}

// Call the toggleSidebar function to initialize the sidebar
toggleSidebar();
```

Error message which I get is as below. I do not understand why I am getting the error as below please anyone suggest me.

[image]

I tried everything whitelisting the resources in web_accessible_resources and making sure content security policy is also set.

Comment: From the docs *getURL : Converts a relative path within an app/extension install directory to a fully-qualified URL*. So, you cannot use it for a domain. Try setting `src` as just a plain string.

Comment: Remove `chrome.runtime.getURL(` and the closing `)`.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much.  @wOxxOm

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks to you too for explaining why it does not work.